# Scripting Stored procedures in SQL 2012 in Transact SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

Stored procedures are being scripted in dynamic SQL when I use 

`"Check for object existence = True"` option. If this is set to false, scripts are coming out in T-SQL. Is there a way where I can generate scripts in T-SQL with `"Check for object existence = True"`.
I know this is working perfectly in 2008 R2. Is this a drawback in 2012? Please let me know if there is any alternate to overcome this?

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

there is a MS connect item [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/709946/script-stored-procedure-view-function-produces-sp-executesql-with-dynamic-sql) that describes the behavior. It's **closed** as **by design**.

If you read all the comments of that item, you will find a set of useful links that redirect to two additional connect items.
Since is closed by design and explained, I guess we've to **workaround manually** as suggested ont his [item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/242799/ssms-certain-scripting-options-yield-dynamic-sql).